# T-SQL Query That Returns lower case Results Only

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table named "KEYWORDS" with a column named "ENTRY" of VARCHAR(10). Would it be possible to retrieve only the lower-case entries from that table?

For example, the table might look like this:

```
ENTRY
===========
SearchString
Searchstring
searchstring
SEARCHSTRING
```

And I would like to be able to run a query that looks similar to:

```
SELECT ENTRY FROM KEYWORDS WHERE ENTRY <condition to retun only the lowercase entry>
```

where the result of the above would be:  `searchstring`

And if that can be done, then I would like to be able to retrieve only the ProperCase entries next.  This is a hosted SQL Server 2005 database on GoDaddy.com hosting so I dont know much about how its configured.  I do not have permission to run EXEC sp_help *DatabaseName*

I will reference this page:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/case-sensitive-sql-query-search/
which was interesting to read because its similar to what I am looking for but different in that the person running the query knows what they are looking for.

I would like ALL entries that are lowercase.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
where Entry COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = Lower(entry)
```

Comment: nicer than my answer and probably a touch faster

Answer (score 3):

This works ...

```
create table #t (entry varchar(10))
insert #t values ('hello'), ('Hello'), ('HELLO')

select * from #t where cast(entry as varbinary(max)) = cast(LOWER(entry) as varbinary(max))

/*
entry
----------
hello
*/
```

Comment: thank you.  This works however @Ramy has a shorter version but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me in SSMS 2012.  I used the Lower that was posted above but not the COLLATE.

```
select Lower(varchar or text) from Table
```

my learning curve with SQL has died a bit but I'm still learning a great deal.

Comment: this isn't actualy correct - this will force the contents returned to be lower case - even if they weren't saved as lower case. The OP was looking for the records stored as lower case.

Comment: I may have misunderstood. I thought the result needed to be lowercase no matter what data was being queried. 

select lower(record) from TableName